# Is there a way to respond to input() from within your code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently made a python package and now I am making piece of code to automate the process of updating the package.
In my code I do:

```py
os.system('twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*')
```

When my code executes that line, it says `Enter your username:` and I want to respond with `__token__` to that input prompt.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you actually need to do this? There is a `--username` command line option. There is also a `TWINE_USERNAME` environment variable. According to https://pypi.org/project/twine/

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the password field as well?

Comment: Yes. See the page I linked.

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out, just used the `--pasword` option, instead of commenting, can you put this in the `Answer Question` section so I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I'll leave it as a comment because it doesn't answer the question as stated. If this question doesn't need an answer, then so be it. Glad you have something that works.